# Cannot plot all data in box-plotting in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining, boxplot

I wanted to make a box plot. I have more than 1000 rows but when I am plotting them, it shows only a few entries.

> Dataset:
>   https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgaqfgm2gkl7i3r/maintenance_data_updated.csv

```
   #Start of Box plot Temperature
    training_data <- read.csv("C:/Users/akhan/Documents/maintenance_data_updated_2.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    library(dplyr)
    dt_temperature <- select(training_data, Runtime, Defect, Machine, Temperature, Plant)
    dt_temperature$Machine_Plant = paste(dt_temperature$Machine,dt_temperature$Plant,sep = "_")
    attach(dt_temperature)
    class(Temperature)
    class(Defect)
    class(Runtime)
    class(Machine)
    ?boxplot
    boxplot(Temperature ~ Machine_Plant)
```

> Current output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nv5n80en1vpkyt/Rplot01.png

Can anyone please give a hint what is the solution ?

Comment: are you sure that Machine_Plant variable is a factor? Try: boxplot(Temperature ~ as.factor(Machine_Plant))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean saying 'it shows only a few entries'? If your problem is about having only 4 boxplots annotated on X-axis, solution could be like this:

```
boxplot(Temperature ~ Machine_Plant, las=3)
```

Type

```
?par
```

for more information about `las` parameter.